# How to grab things from xcassets?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to grab image from my xcasserts folder and I did this in my code :

```
 if (self.emailField.text.isEmpty ) {
        self.emailIcon.image = UIImage.animatedImageNamed("Images.xcasserts/caution", duration: 0.2)
    }
```

but it doesn't work , how to write xcasserts address properly ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things.

1. You don't have to specify the asset catalog's name. You can simply use,

   `self.emailIcon.image = UIImage.animatedImageNamed("caution", duration: 0.2)`
2. The other thing is, its not xcasserts. Its `xcassets`.

Comment: thx lsuru , however I followed you instruction the image still haven't been displayed ..

Comment: ok I found the problem. xcassets only display the name but not the suffix of the file , after i specify "caution" to "caution.png" which I found in picture's attribute menu it works, thanks!